# Ayuda, insertar registros en tablas relacionadas usando php oo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html5, pdo

Un saludo amigos, desde ayer estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio pero no le hallo solución de momento. Tengo 2 tablas en mi BBDD una llamada **ts_cliente** y otra **ts_equipo**, la relación es **1:n** un cliente puede tener muchos equipos. Anteriormente podía anexar registros de manera exitosa, pero luego que cree la relación **1:n** se complico un poco, ya que es la primera vez que trabajo con tablas relacionadas.

Estuve leyendo algunas soluciones que presentan por internet, segun entendi debo tomar el **id** de mi tabla **ts_cliente** para luego trabajar en base a ese id con la tabla **ts_equipo**; me puse manos a la obra pero solo me surge error tras error. Aclaro que estoy usando **pdo oo**, dejo una imagen de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en Registrar equipo se envian los valores por medio de una funcion la cual insertara los datos en la BBDD

```
if(isset($_POST['agregar_equipo'])){

    $ced = $_POST['cedu_cli'];
    $nomb = $_POST['nomb_cli'];
    $aped = $_POST['aped_cli'];
    $telf = $_POST['telf_cli'];
    $direc = $_POST['dire_cli'];

    $equipo = $_POST['equipo'];
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];
    $model= $_POST['modelo'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $fech = $_POST['fecha'];        

    $persona = new usuario();
    $persona->insertarCliente($ced, $nomb, $aped, $telf, $direc, $equipo, $marca, $model, $serial, $fech);
}
```

**Aqui la funcion que se encarga de procesar los datos**

```
public function insertarCliente($ced, $nomb, $aped, $telf, $direc, $equipo, $marca, $model, $serial, $fech){

    // Compruebo que las variables no esten vacias
    if(empty($ced) || empty($nomb) || empty($aped) || empty($telf) || empty($direc)){
        header('Location: pagina_clientes.php');
    }else{

        $comprobar = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ts_cliente WHERE cli_ced = $ced LIMIT 1";
        $existe = $this->db_conexion->query($comprobar);

        // Si ya existe la cedula simplemente registro el equipo
        if($existe->fetchColumn() > 0){

            $valor = "SELECT cli_id FROM ts_cliente WHERE cli_ced = $ced LIMIT 1";
            $cli_id = $this->db_conexion->query($valor);
            $last_id = $cli_id->fetch();

            $id = $last_id['cli_id'];

            $insertar = "INSERT INTO ts_equipo (equ_nom, equ_mar, equ_mod, equ_ser, equ_fec, cli_id) VALUES ($equipo, $marca, $model, $serial, $fech, $id)";
            $resultado = $this->db_conexion->query($insertar);

            header('location: pagina_equipos.php');
            $resultado->closeCursor();
            $cli_id->closeCursor();

        }

        // Caso contrario registro al cliente y el equipo
        else{

            $insertar = "INSERT INTO ts_cliente (cli_ced, cli_nom, cli_ape, cli_tel, cli_dir) VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :d, :e)";
            $resultado = $this->db_conexion->prepare($insertar);
            $resultado->execute(array(':a'=>$ced,':b'=>$nomb,':c'=>$aped,':d'=>$telf,':e'=>$direc));
            $last_id = $this->db_conexion->lastInsertId();

            $insertar2 = "INSERT INTO ts_equipo (equ_nom, equ_mar, equ_mod, equ_ser, equ_fec, cli_id) VALUES ($equipo, $marca, $model, $serial, $fech, $last_id)";
            $resultado2 = $this->db_conexion->query($insertar2);

            header('location: pagina_equipos.php');

            $resultado->closeCursor();              
            $resultado2->closeCursor();
        }

        $existe->closeCursor();
        $this->db_conexion = null;
    }
}
```

Ese fue el ultimo codigo que probe, anteriormente tenia una función para registrar los equipos y desde la función que registra los clientes llamaba a la funcion de equipos... Pero me generaba varios errores, y pues pensé que con esta forma podría funcionar pero el resultado fue el mismo :(

Perdonen si derrepente tengo errores en la implementacion del codigo, pero de esta manera fue que lo entendi (y doy por echo que esta mal)... Por eso recurro a ustedes compañeros, para que me orienten en el tema; ya entendiendo esta parte del codigo puedo terminar de relacionar mis otras tablas. Bendiciones

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la BD? ¿Ambas tablas tienen foreign keys que se apuntan mutuamente?

Comment: Sería bueno que indiques los errores que te estaba dando. Por ejemplo, si tenías errores del tipo `DUPLICATE ENTRY...`, o de otro tipo.

Comment: @AlbertoTorre la tabla ts_cliente y la tabla ts_equipo estan relacionadas entre sí. En el caso de la tabla ts_equipo, tiene un atributo cli_id que viene siendo la FK. y la relación es de 1:n

Comment: @A.Cedano El error como tal me lo da es al insertar los datos del equipo, el cliente lo inserta bien... Aunque con las ultimas modificaciones que le hice dejo de insertar registros en ambas tablas... Si pudieran darme un ejemplo sencillo de como trabajar tablas relacionadas con pdo se los agradecería, es que no se si lo este haciendo de la manera correcta y quiero tener un concepto mas claro respecto al tema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código puede estar fallando porque alguno de los INSERT crea datos duplicados, o porque hay error de sintaxis.

Creo que es preciso normalizar tus consultas de inserción, aplicando en cada una de ellas consultas preparadas. En una lo aplicas, pero en otra no. También tu consulta `SELECT` y **toda consulta que meneje datos provenientes desde el exterior debe aplicar dicha práctica**, de lo contrario tu código será altamente vulnerable.

Por otra parte, la consulta primera que hace con `COUNT` es innecesaria. En PDO, si quieres saber que existen datos, puedes evaluar los mismos datos. No necesitas en este caso hacer una consulta con COUNT primero para luego hacer casi la misma consulta para obtener el id. Mejor haz la consulta que obtiene el id, haz un fetch de esa columna y evalúa la variable. Si es `FALSE` significará que no hay datos con ese criterio. Y si no lo es ¡ya tienes el dato!, no tienes que hacer un segundo viaje para buscarlo.

En el código he tratado de evaluar las posibles ocurrencias haciendo las redirecciones solamente cuando la inserción se haga. He tratado de controlarlo todo, pero puede que algo se me haya escapado.

Yo re-escribiría la función así:

```
public function insertarCliente($ced, $nomb, $aped, $telf, $direc, $equipo, $marca, $model, $serial, $fech){

    // Compruebo que las variables no esten vacias
    if(empty($ced) || empty($nomb) || empty($aped) || empty($telf) || empty($direc)){
        header('Location: pagina_clientes.php');

    }else{
        $ql = "SELECT cli_id FROM ts_cliente WHERE cli_ced = :a LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $this->db_conexion->prepare($sql);
        $arrParams=array(':a'=>$ced);
        $stmt->execute($arrParams);
        $cli_id=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($cli_id){
            $stmt->close();
            $id=$cli_id["cli_id"];
            $insertar = "INSERT INTO ts_equipo (equ_nom, equ_mar, equ_mod, equ_ser, equ_fec, cli_id) VALUES (:a, :b, c:, d:, e:, :f)";            
            $arrParams=array(":a"=>$equipo, ":b"=>$marca, ":c"=>$model, ":d"=>$serial, ":e"=>$fech, ":f"=>$id);
            $stmt = $this->db_conexion->prepare($insertar);
            $insertar=$stmt->execute($arrParams);

            if ($insertar){
                $stmt->close();
                $this->db_conexion = null;
                header('location: pagina_equipos.php');

            }else{
                $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Fallo insert".$stmt->errorInfo()[2]);
            }               

        }else{

            $insertar = "INSERT INTO ts_cliente (cli_ced, cli_nom, cli_ape, cli_tel, cli_dir) VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :d, :e)";
            $stmt = $this->db_conexion->prepare($insertar);
            $arrParams=array(':a'=>$ced,':b'=>$nomb,':c'=>$aped,':d'=>$telf,':e'=>$direc);
            $nuevo=$stmt->execute($arrParams);

            if ($nuevo){
                $id = $this->db_conexion->lastInsertId();
                $insertar = "INSERT INTO ts_equipo (equ_nom, equ_mar, equ_mod, equ_ser, equ_fec, cli_id) VALUES (:a, :b, c:, d:, e:, :f)";
                $arrParams=array(":a"=>$equipo, ":b"=>$marca, ":c"=>$model, ":d"=>$serial, ":e"=>$fech, ":f"=>$id);
                $stmt = $this->db_conexion->prepare($insertar);
                $insertar=$stmt->execute($arrParams);

                if ($insertar){
                    $stmt->close();
                    $this->db_conexion = null;
                    header('location: pagina_equipos.php');

                }else{
                    $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Fallo insert".$stmt->errorInfo()[2]);
                }

            }else{
                    $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Fallo insert".$stmt->errorInfo()[2]);
            }


        }
    }


    if ($arrMensaje){

        echo $arrMensaje["mensaje"];
    }


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan detallada respuesta hermano ^_^ ya me quedo todo mas claro, tambien gracias por las observaciones, cada día se aprende algo nuevo... Pues no estaba normalizando el INSERT de ts_equipo ya que me daba un error y quería ver quien era el causante, de echo lo sigue generando SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. Aunque solo se da con el registro de ts_equipo, ya verifique y el numero de variables coinciden, tambien probé asignando los parámetros de la función a variables pero no funciono.

Comment: ¿Haz verificado que ninguna de las variables es un array? Es el único motivo que veo por el que podría dar ese error, ya que la cantidad de parámetros coinciden. Haz un var_dump de $arrParams para verificar lo que estás pasando en cada INSERT

Comment: ya verifique y sale esto: array (size=6)
  ':a' => string 'Computadora' (length=11)
  ':b' => string 'HP' (length=2)
  ':c' => string 'Pavilion' (length=8)
  ':d' => string '123456' (length=6)
  ':e' => string '2017-11-18' (length=10)
  ':f' => string '2' (length=1)

Comment: Ya di con la solución hermano ^_^ resulta que había puesto c: y d: por eso generaba el error, fallo mio :D muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya comprendí como trabajar con tablas relacionadas que era mi objetivo.. DTB hermano y muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Por cierto me parece mas confiable primero contar los registros y luego hacer una condición para verificar si es mayor a 0... Realice varias prueba con un código de login y registro, de la manera como menciono trabaja correctamente... pero si hago una condición booleana (true / false) no trabaja del todo bien, ya que aveces dice haber registros cuando no los hay. Aunque solo es en ciertos casos, creo que depende de como se implemente el código. Solo quería acotar esa información, saludos hermano.